# How to find opened window in ZK?

Tags: zk

I have a button in my zul file. So, I want to open only one instance of window (in another zul file) when I click it.
How can I check if a window is opened?

This is my zul file:

```
<zk>
<window id="windowOverlapped" title="Test" width="800px" height="auto" mode="overlapped" >      
    TEST!
</window>
</zk>
```

I open, through the button, the window in the controller with this code:

```
Executions.createComponents("/test.zul", null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

The query could be omitted if the `Window` is the root element of the .zul file.

```
Window win = Executions.createComponents("/test.zul", null, null).query("windowOverlapped")

...
if( win.inOverlapped() ) ....
...
```